# Flask app double webhook execution problem

Tags: python, flask, webhooks

I have created a python flask app that receives web hook alerts from trading view and execute them on brokers account. The problem is if  stop loss is triggered after entry in trading view  it send two stop loss orders at same time and same syntax its because I use partial profit exit. ISSUE is when I receive two alerts at same time due to flask concurrency it execute both orders and I get extra position in my brokers account. here is the below code for better understanding

```
@app.route('/webhook_pivot', methods=[ 'POST'])
def webhook():
    # Get the data from the request
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    data_str = json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True)
    #print("Incoming webhook data:", data)
    side = data['side']
    qty = int(data['qty'] ) * int(lot)

    if side == "BUY" :

        #buy  execution code here.....

    elif side == "FULL_EXIT_BUY" and check_symbol_and_position(sym):

        with lock:
            if data_str in cache:

                # If the data is in the cache, it's a duplicate and should be ignored
                print("Double msg ignore")
                return "Duplicate data, ignoring"

            else:
                time.sleep(0.7)
                # BUY EXIT order ...but it send this part twice ..!!! the problem
```

Answer (score 0):

After no one gave me any answer here I knew I am own my own, but I have finally solved the problem by using sqlite3 db for storing alerts. When I get buy exit all alert  it process the alert and store the alert id in the database with unique id and and when the same alert comes at same time its ignored it as a duplicate.